# Need help with getting NoMachine working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, freenx

I'm trying to get `NoMachine` working on a AWS EC2 instance with 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

I’ve used the instructions from:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX
- http://javadude.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/running-ubuntu-12-04-desktop-on-ec2/

When I try to connect from my Mac using NoMachine 4.2.21, I get this error:

```
The connection with the server was lost.
Error is 54: Connection reset by peer.
```

When I use the OpenNX 0.16.0.729 client, I get a blank black screen.

Help.

Comment: do you see anything more specific in   /usr/NX/var/log/   ??

Answer (score 0):

What helped with me is disabling `light locker`.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get remove light-locker
"Package 'light-locker' is not installed, so not removed"